# Why is this failing after 3 iterations?

Tags: nodemcu

I simply cannot figure this out, why is this failing after 3 iterations? Other than that, what better way is there to do this? Thanks!

```
#define rotary_encoder_topic  "/rotary/encoder"
#define remote_button_topic  "/remote/button"
#define remote_2x_toggle_topic  "/remote/2xtoggle"
#define rotary_button_topic  "/rotary/button";
char* devices[] = { "ledrpi", "lamprpi", "mediaroom" };
int currentDevice = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void incrementCurrentDevice() {
  currentDevice++;
  if (currentDevice >= sizeof(devices)) {
    currentDevice = 0;
  }
 Serial.println(concatenateChars("Switched device to: ", devices[currentDevice]));
}

char* concatenateChars(const char* one, const char* two) {
  char result[150] = "";
  strcat(result, one);
  strcat(result, two);
  return result;
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(concatenateChars(devices[currentDevice], remote_2x_toggle_topic));
  incrementCurrentDevice();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: what does `failing` mean?

Answer (score 1):

As Jaromanda X pointed out in the comments, `sizeof(array[0])` (size of first element) will not return the size of the literal strings, but the size of a `char` pointer.

---

It doesn't work (whatever that means for you), because `sizeof(devices)` doesn't return the number of entries in the array, but the size of the array in bytes, e.g. something like (following is wrong: 24 (1 byte per character plus 1 byte with the concluding null character for each string) ) 6 (The size of a `char` pointer is 2 bytes on most microcontrollers; I'm not sure, if this is the same for Node MCU). So after 3 iterations (which can use the string literals in the array) `currentDevice` doesn't go back to zero, but counts further. With the access to the array with exceeding index you are accessing memory, that doesn't belong to the array anymore (e.g. random data).

There is no native function, that gives you the length of an array. But it can be calculated with `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, which is the size of the array in bytes divided by the size of one element in bytes. In your case you would have an array size of 6 and an element size of 2, resulting in a calculated element count of 3, which is correct.

Another simple solution, which is easier to understand for beginners, but not as flexible, is to set a constant or define, that contains the size of your array. You can then use it in your code, whenever you need the size, including, when you define the array.

Comment: actually wouldn't `sizeof(devices)` return 3 x `sizeof(char *)` so, the length of each string is irrelevant. therefore `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` will give `3` in this case, guaranteed

Comment: of course, I meant `sizeof(devices)/sizeof(devices[0])`

Comment: @JaromandaX Mhh, I haven't thought of this. But I think, you are right. The size of a pointer is 2 bytes, as I remember. So it will count to 6. Is this the same for a Node MCU? And yes, the division should work either way.

Comment: knowing size of the pointer doesn't actually matter :D

Comment: It doesn't matter for this case, but I was interested